# laser_assembler while moving

Tags: ros, laser-assembler

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

This question is to clarify something. According to http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_assembler the individual scans are projected into a fixed frame right? So, that means we can readily use the assembled cloud in process like octomap even when the robot is moving. I mean we do not need the robot to stop and acquire the cloud.

Is this correct?

Thanks

CS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37375/laser_assembler-while-moving/) by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 387 on 2012-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, if the fixed_frame stays fixed during movement (something like /map or /odom).

However, you might not get perfectly matching data depending on the accuracy of whoever produces the fixed_frame transformation.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) on 2012-06-27**:
Thank you! @dornhege